# Errors encountered when installing kubuntu on 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, dpkg, 15.04

I ran:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

and after it gave me this error message:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and whenever I try to install a new program or run the suggested solution to this problem, which was mentioned after I tried to install another program, `sudo apt-get -f install` I get the same error message again.

## EDIT: Requested outputs.

```
sudo apt-get --configure -a
```

gives [this](https://goo.gl/z0c3hg) (too large to fit in the question).

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
The following NEW packages will be installed
  kde-config-telepathy-accounts
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 23 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/131 kB of archives.
After this operation, 697 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 1088636 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

while running:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

gives:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid universe
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid multiverse
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid contrib
```

Comment: have you run `sudo apt-get update` after adding ppa?

Comment: Sure did, just added it to my question, sorry I forgot it at first.

Comment: Add output of these, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`   ,    `sudo apt-get install -f`  ,   `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Requested info added to question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the problem:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.1-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2
```

Therefore two command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge account-plugin-google
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I had to run this too:  `sudo dpkg -r  account-plugin-google unity-scope-gdrive`

Answer (score 0):

I saw the attached link.

I think you need to do:-

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge kde-telepathy-minimal
sudo apt-get remove --purge kde-telepathy
```

Also, try to remove orphaned packages using `apt-get autoremove`

**EDIT:** If that didn't work, try installing Aptitude:

Install aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get aptitude
```

Run it:

```
sudo aptitude purge kde-telepathy
sudo aptitude purge kde-telepathy-minimal
```

Comment: Both give the same error: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 kde-telepathy : Depends: kde-telepathy-minimal (= 15.04.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Comment: @BrentonHorne you somehow need to remove those two packages! Try the edited answer after running a `apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug already reported in Ubuntu, Kubuntu PPA and also in KDE:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kaccounts-providers/+bug/1488909
https://bugs.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/+bug/1451728
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347219