# How do I fix Ubuntu 15.04 when I cannot seem to boot it?

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04

I followed both Sharad's and A.B.'s answers (both of them) on a [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634475/errors-encountered-when-installing-kubuntu-on-15-04) about Kubuntu. I then rebooted LXDE and managed to get into Grub, I then selected to run Ubuntu, normally (i.e., the default option given) and while it seemed to be loading normally (i.e., it showed the Ubuntu logo with the five circles that change their colour to reflect that Ubuntu is loading) for a while after that, it eventually left me at a blank black screen with only my mouse cursor visible. I waited patiently for this to pass, I assumed it was only temporary but it didn't pass, after twenty minutes of waiting nothing happened. So at this time I am on my live USB (in "Try Ubuntu" mode) and hoping someone in this grand community can help me. I don't have anything on my Ubuntu installation I'd deeply lament being rid of, aside from my MediaWiki installation (if there's a way to do a mysql dump from my live USB I'd love to hear it).

## Following [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), issues

When following [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), this is what editing the Ubuntu boot option gives
[image]
[image]

Changing `quiet splash` to `nomodeset` allows me to boot (and even login) but the computer is incredibly laggy, graphics-wise. Like there's trails of black pixels left by the mouse cursor. While the other options like `acpi=off` or `nolapic` gets me to the login window, but freezes and reverts to the screen described at the start of this question. Everything is so laggy and prone to these stream of black pixels following my mouse cursor I can't even open a web browser and read stuff in it. See when I open a web browser, it opens but the blank pixels pop up when I scroll down in the browser. So I think the best option is for someone to work out how I might fix the problem that occurred with the changes recommended (in the answers) in the [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634475/errors-encountered-when-installing-kubuntu-on-15-04) I linked.

Comment: Try booting with `nomodset` and if that did not work, try with `acpi = off` and `nolapic`as described in http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Just to be clear you mean to boot into my live USB and not into my hard drive?

Comment: Boot live CD/USB and hit down-arrow when you see the live CD/USB booting (as described in the previous link) to get the advanced options from where you can select those options.

Comment: Um as I understand it that guide, section 2 (i.e., that entitled **2. Black/purple screen when you try to boot the LiveCD**) is meant for those having trouble booting from live USB. I am having no issues with booting from live USB, it's my hard drive installation that's generating problems. I tried your solution, both with and without `acpi=off` and `nolapic`. I then logged out of the live session and rebooted from my hard drive and I experienced the same error again.

Comment: look at the "Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time" section. You will have to change the kernel boot parameters to whatever works for you (acpi=off, nolapic or nomodset) later.

Comment: I edited my question to include results of your suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by going to my live USB and erasing my hard disk drive (HDD) and installing Ubuntu 15.04 again on the HDD.

I initially tried the non-destructive method of installation, namely one where only the system-related files (like those in `/usr/bin`) are replaced, not the user files like those in `/home/fusion809/`, but this failed. Several programs were also uninstalled, although I was asked during installation whether I wanted these programs to be reinstalled, I selected that I wanted them to be reinstalled. Later in the installation of Ubuntu from within my live session (I can confirm my internet connection was fine on this live session), however, I was informed that an error had occurred that prevented the installation of these additional programs from the live session. After rebooting from the live session I was able to login successfully into my main installation, so a partial success was achieved, but my internet connection could no longer be established.

So I eventually opted to erase my HDD and install Ubuntu 15.04 from scratch on the HDD, after I had backed up the files I absolutely needed.

This issue reoccurred when I reinstalled Kubuntu on this new installation. It is likely a bug.